# Построение фракталов c++

Tags: c++, математика, фракталы

Как подойти к построению фракталов на с++?
Можно ли строить рандомные фракталы? или по вводимым признакам? или вообще динамические и меняющие цвета? 
Есть ли примеры/полезные статьи/код у тех, кто с этим сталкивался?

Comment: Ну, регулярные самоподобные фракталы в силу своего самоподобия хорошо строятся рекурсивными функциями - те же ковры Серпинского, снежинки Коха и т.п. Но вообще ваш вопрос столь всеобъемлющ, что дать на него однозначный ответ практически невозможно.